# Huge movement delay

Tags: unity-game-engine, google-vr-sdk

I am working with VR and found a big problem in step one. I followed the most basic tutorial and everything works fine until I try the app on my phone.

Even though the scene is extremely basic (just one plane, medium quality settings) there is a huge delay between the movement of the head and the app responding. I have a total amount of 2 Draw Calls, 2 Batches, 1.9k Tris. Frame rate on pc is 4000 Fps!. So it definitely is not an optimization issue.

I have unity updated to 2017.2.0f3 and GVR is version 1.100.1. My phone is a Huawei P8 Lite 2017.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what tutorial you followed but it shouldn't have this issue. My suggestion is begin an empty new project, import GVR SDK and try to build the DEMO scene... check out if this works fast or slow.